# clarifying understanding of expectation of the absolute value of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Given pdf f(x), is $\mathbb{E}(|X|)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|f(|x|)$? why would it not be $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(|x|)$ or $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x||f(x)|$?

Comment: I believe it should be $\sum |x|f(x)$.

Comment: In the last one, no need for absolute value around $f(x)$ since it's a density so nonnegative already.

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: A PDF is integrated, not summed.  Writing $\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}$ means you are only summing over integers. Writing $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ leaves ambiguous what the summation index is. If $X$ were a discrete random variable then using $\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}$ would still be incorrect unless we were told that $X$ takes only integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $g$ is a function and $X$ is a (real) random variable with pdf $f$
$$
E[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f(x)\,dx. 
$$
In your case, $g(\cdot)=|\cdot|$.